# SQL select query returns duplicate

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I query according to this string and I expect to get unique IDs but I got a duplicate for each record.

Here is the code:

```
select 
    logs.id, to_char( login, 'YYYY-mm-dd') as time, 
    members.facility_id as facility, province, 
    district, count(members.id) as value 
from 
    members 
left join 
    system_data on system_data.facility_id = members.facility_id 
left join 
    logs on logs.card_id = members.card_id 
         and members.facility_id = logs.facility_id  
where
    ('2022-08-01' <= login and login <= '2022-08-11') 
    and province is not null 
group by 
    facility, time, province, district, logs.id 
order by 
    logs.id;
```

How can I prevent duplicates? Why do I get duplicates?

Comment: You must have a one-to-many join if you are seeing duplicates. Such as can a member have multiple facilities?

Comment: can you provide some data with the behaviour see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You get one result row per facility, time, province, district, and logs.id, just as stated in your `GROUP BY` clause. It sounds natural to get more than one row per ID (log.id I assume?) hence. Do you want `GROUP BY logs.id` instead?

Comment: We don't know your tables. Can there be multiple rows per card_id and facility_id in the members table? Can there be multiple rows per card_id and facility_id in the logs table? Can there be multiple rows per facility_id in the system_data table? Then, which tables do the columns belong to? You should qualify each column in the query with the table it belongs to (like you do with the logs' id).

Comment: On a side note: Is the login column a string? If it is a date, you should compare it with a date, not with a string: `login <= date '2022-08-11'`.

Comment: I solved it by fixing where clause  ```and province not in('') ``` . There where 2 system data and one of them was empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by fixing where clause and `province not in('')`  . There where 2 system data and one of them was empty